# Why is it grainy in this part?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have no idea why is it grainy on the left side. But on the right side it is ok. I added additional lights on the left side but the problem is still there. Any tips? I am struggling about lighting the rooms.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Artifatcs are caused by overlapping faces.

On the right side you have this situation (correct):

[image]

while on the left side (overlapped/dubled geometry):

[image]

You can clearly see the problem also in Solid view display mode.

[image]

As faces shares the same location, camera rays can't tell which one is visible from camera, so shows a bit of one and a bit of the other.

You have to create a gap between faces

Comment: i deleted the overlapping objects and it's ok already. Thank you. Sorry for this noob question

Answer (score 0):

your green wall's face is overlaping the other wall (behind it). move it a tiny bit away.
(i also suggest you to make your roof a bit less shiny with a lower specular intensity and hardness)